# Class value accessible from multiple files and functions c++

Tags: c++, class

I apologize before-hand if this question has been asked before.

I put all my skills with google to use and still nothing so if this question has been answered before please just link the answer and I'll essentially end the question.

Anyway, with all that out of the way, my problem is that I have a class "Player.hpp" and a corresponding "Player.cpp" in which I have defined the location system for the "player" I can initialize the value fine (which is one of the functions of the class) but then when the player goes to the "play()" function (which holds the bones of the game and is located in another .cpp file) when I use the function to get the Location I stored there is nothing stored... any help would be appreciated.

If you don't understand what I'm asking please comment and I'll elaborate.

Code Below:

```
//Player.hpp
class player
{
public:
    std::string getLocation();
    void setLocation(std::string local);
    void initLocation();

private:
    std::string location;
};

//Player.cpp
void player::initLocation()
{
    player::location = "B0";
    return;
}
std::string player::getLocation()
{
    return player::location;
}
void player::setLocation(std::string local)
{
    player::location = local;
    return;
}

//Main.cpp
//....
player plays;
plays.initLocation();
//....

//Game.cpp
//...
player plays;
std::string local = plays.getLocation(); //When I check there isn't a value that gets stored...
if(local.find(...)...)
```

Again, any help is appreciated and I apologize if a question like this has already been asked.

## Edit:

I guess I should have clarified that I also want to change the value stored as the `player` progresses from room to room (as this is a zork style game I'm making)

Comment: Did you really create a different instance of `player` in `Game.cpp` than what you initialized in `Main.cpp`? If so, that's your problem.

Comment: How are you "checking" that "there isn't a value that gets stored"?

Comment: @jxh well I'm not too sure how to go about that (as I'm still extremely new to programming) but I'll see about looking up the information.  @Kerrek SB I check it by displaying the value from local after it has "supposedly" received the data from `getLocation()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that each instance of `player` could be in a separate location, you can resolve this issue by initializing the `player`'s location with the default location in its constructor. This removes the need for `initLocation()`, and thus there is no need to call it from `Main.cpp`.

```
//Player.hpp
class player
{
public:
    std::string getLocation();
    void setLocation(std::string local);

    player () : location("B0") {}

private:
    std::string location;
};
```

Comment: Okay so it worked ... it just lead me to find out I have a very different problem which I can work out...

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you omitted `static` in front of the class variable declaration:

```
class player
{
    // ...
    static std::string location;
};
```

... which then also requires a definition. Of course, the definition becomes a prime location to also initialize the value:

```
// Player.cpp
std:string player::location("B0");
```

making the initialization function unnecessary.

Comment: `static` won't work because I need to be able to change the value of location so that I can load it from anywhere and it still be the correct set value.